# How to get a latest files from a different location

Tags: powershell-3.0

I want to copy the latest/modified files from a folder to another in PowerShell.

I am able to use the code below to see the latest files based on the LastWriteTime but I don't know how to copy them to another folder.

```
$latest = Get-ChildItem $dir -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code collects the required files into a `$latest` variable. Afterwards, the files, specified in the variable can be moved as follows:

```
Copy-Item $latest -Destination D:\Tmp -Recurse
```

Another way is to use the command pipeline instead of collecting the files into the variable:

```
Get-ChildItem $dir -Recurse | Where-Object {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-7)} | Copy-Item -Destination D:\Tmp -Recurse
```

Obviously, you can use any other directory or variable instead of D:\Tmp